# Spring social facebook login - sorry, something went wrong

Tags: java, spring, facebook, oauth, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my spring webapp using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-facebook`, However everytime I follow the login flow I get this page at facebook host:

[image: Error message]

Here's my setup:

- Added appId and secret:

**application.properties**

```
spring.social.facebook.appId=xxx
spring.social.facebook.appSecret=xxx
```

- In facebook developer page I enabled **facebook login** product and added `http://localhost:8080/connect/facebook` as my redirect uri.
- Wrote a login form:

**connect/facebook.html**

```
<form th:action="@{/connect/facebook}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="user_posts"/>
    <button type="submit">Connect to Facebook</button>
</form>
```

That redirects me to this url:
`https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&response_type=code&_csrf=732c940f-37fc-406b-b08b-d591e0e372a3&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fconnect%2Ffacebook&scope=user_posts&state=8ec3aaa3-972e-401e-b47f-930f654f6fd8`

I think that `_csrf` is not required here and came from spring's csrf injector, but it shouldn't make any difference anyway.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? The error message is not verbose at all and I'm not sure where can I start troubleshooting.

Comment: It looks like there is a failure by facebook, the Text written under Sorry, somethink... sounds that there is a temporary Problem on there site. What if you verify your Facebook Developer Account as here described:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-register-facebook-app ?

Comment: recreate app on facebook

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, in my case

1- Property was not being loaded correctly which causes facebook to say Sorry against invalid `app-id` and `app-secret`. So make sure your app id and secret are OK.

2- In redirect URI from facebook app dashboard just put `http://localhost:8080/` 
then it should work.

For more help and guide, you can check [github](https://github.com/MFaisalHyder/SpringSocialMVC) project I created due to such issues faced by majority while using Spring Social.